# My A-star implementation seems very slow, need advice and help on what I am doing wrong

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, graph-algorithm, a-star

My tests of my implementations of Dijkstra and A-Star have revealed that my A-star implementation is approximately 2 times **SLOWER**. Usually equivalent implementations of Dijkstra and A-star should see A-star beating out Dijkstra. But that isn't the case here and so it has led me to question my implementation of A-star. So I want someone to tell me what I am doing wrong in my implementation of A-star.

Here is my code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from math import inf, sqrt
import maze_builderV2 as mb

if __name__ == '__main__':
    order = 10
    space = ['X']+['_' for x in range(order)]+['X']
    maze = [deepcopy(space) for x in range(order)]
    maze.append(['X' for x in range(order+2)])
    maze.insert(0, ['X' for x in range(order+2)])

    finalpos = (order, order)

    pos = (1, 1)

    maze[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 'S'  # Initializing a start position
    maze[finalpos[0]][finalpos[1]] = 'O'  # Initializing a end position

    mb.mazebuilder(maze=maze)

    def spit():
        for x in maze:
            print(x)

    spit()
    print()

    mazemap = {}

    def scan():  # Converts raw map/maze into a suitable datastructure.
        for x in range(1, order+1):
            for y in range(1, order+1):
                mazemap[(x, y)] = {}
                t = [(x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1)]
                for z in t:
                    if maze[z[0]][z[1]] == 'X':
                        pass
                    else:
                        mazemap[(x, y)][z] = [sqrt((pos[0]-z[0])**2+(pos[1]-z[1])**2),
                                            sqrt((finalpos[0]-z[0])**2+(finalpos[1]-z[1])**2)] # Euclidean distance to destination (Heuristic)

    scan()

    unvisited = deepcopy(mazemap)
    distances = {}
    paths = {}

    # Initialization of distances:
    for node in unvisited:
        if node == pos:
            distances[node] = [0, sqrt((finalpos[0]-node[0])**2+(finalpos[1]-node[1])**2)]
        else:
            distances[node] = [inf, inf]

    while unvisited != {}:
        curnode = None
        for node in unvisited:
            if curnode == None:
                curnode = node
            elif (distances[node][0]+distances[node][1]) < (distances[curnode][0]+distances[curnode][1]):
                curnode = node
            else:
                pass

        for childnode, lengths in mazemap[curnode].items():
            # Length to nearby childnode - G length, Euclidean (Heuristic) length from curnode to finalpos - H length
            # G length + H length < Euclidean length to reach that childnode directly + Euclidean length to finalpos from that childnode = Better path found, update known distance and paths
            if lengths[0] + lengths[1] < distances[childnode][0] + distances[childnode][1]:
                distances[childnode] = [lengths[0], lengths[1]]
                paths[childnode] = curnode

        unvisited.pop(curnode)

    def shortestroute(paths, start, end):
        shortestpath = []
        try:
            def rec(start, end):
                if end == start:
                    shortestpath.append(end)
                    return shortestpath[::-1]
                else:
                    shortestpath.append(end)
                    return rec(start, paths[end])
            return rec(start, end)
        except KeyError:
            return False

    finalpath = shortestroute(paths, pos, finalpos)

    if finalpath:
        for x in finalpath:
            if x == pos or x == finalpos:
                pass
            else:
                maze[x[0]][x[1]] = 'W'
    else:
        print("This maze not solvable, Blyat!")
        print()

    spit()
```

For those who find my code too messy and can't bother to read the comments I added to help with the reading... Here is a gist of my code:

- Creates a mazemap (all the coordinates and its connected neighbors along with their euclidean distances from that neighboring point to the start position (G Cost) as well as to the final position (H Cost)... in a dictionary)
- start position is selected as the current node. All distances to other nodes is initialised as infinity.
- For every node we compare the total path cost i.e is the G cost + H cost. The one with least total cost is selected as then next current node. Each time we select new current node, we add that node to a dictionary that keeps track of through which node it was reached, so that it is easier to backtrack and find our path.
- Process continues until current node is the final position.

If anyone can help me out on this, that would be great!

EDIT: On account of people asking for the maze building algorithm, here it is:

```
# Maze generator - v2: Generates mazes that look like city streets (more or less...)

from copy import deepcopy
from random import randint, choice

if __name__ == "__main__":
    order = 10

    space = ['X']+['_' for x in range(order)]+['X']
    maze = [deepcopy(space) for x in range(order)]
    maze.append(['X' for x in range(order+2)])
    maze.insert(0, ['X' for x in range(order+2)])

    pos = (1, 1)
    finalpos = (order, order)

    maze[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 'S'  # Initializing a start position
    maze[finalpos[1]][finalpos[1]] = 'O'  # Initializing a end position

    def spit():
         for x in maze:
             print(x)

    blocks = []
    freespaces = [(x, y) for x in range(1, order+1) for y in range(1, order+1)]

    def blockbuilder(kind):
        param1 = param2 = 0
        double = randint(0, 1)
        if kind == 0:
            param2 = randint(3, 5)
            if double:
                param1 = 2
            else:
                param1 = 1
        else:
            param1 = randint(3, 5)
            if double:
                param2 = 2
            else:
                param2 = 1
        for a in range(blockstarter[0], blockstarter[0]+param2):
            for b in range(blockstarter[1], blockstarter[1]+param1):
                if (a+1, b) in blocks or (a-1, b) in blocks or (a, b+1) in blocks or (a, b-1) in blocks or (a, b) in blocks or (a+1, b+1) in blocks or (a-1, b+1) in blocks or (a+1, b-1) in blocks or (a-1, b-1) in blocks:
                    pass
                else:
                    if a > order+1 or b > order+1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if maze[a][b] == 'X':
                            blocks.append((a, b))
                        else:
                            spaces = [(a+1, b), (a-1, b), (a, b+1), (a, b-1)]
                            for c in spaces:
                                if maze[c[0]][c[1]] == 'X':
                                    break
                                else:
                                    maze[a][b] = 'X'
                                    blocks.append((a, b))

    for x in range(1, order+1):
        for y in range(1, order+1):
            if (x, y) in freespaces:
                t = [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)]
                i = 0
                while i < len(t):
                    if maze[t[i][0]][t[i][1]] == 'X' or (t[i][0], t[i][1]) == pos or (t[i][0], t[i][1]) == finalpos:
                        del t[i]
                    else:
                        i += 1
                if len(t) > 2:
                    blockstarter = t[randint(0, len(t)-1)]
                    kind = randint(0, 1)  # 0 - vertical, 1 - horizontal
                    blockbuilder(kind)
                else:
                    pass

    # rch = choice(['d', 'u', 'r', 'l'])
    b = 0
    while b < len(blocks):
        block = blocks[b]
        t = {'d': (block[0]+2, block[1]), 'u': (block[0]-2, block[1]),
             'r': (block[0], block[1]+2), 'l': (block[0], block[1]-2)}
        rch = choice(['d', 'u', 'r', 'l'])
        z = t[rch]
        # if z[0] > order+1 or z[1] > order+1 or z[0] < 1 or z[1] < 1:
        # Decreased chance of having non solvable maze being generated...
        if z[0] > order-2 or z[1] > order-2 or z[0] < 2+2 or z[1] < 2+2:
            pass
        else:
            if maze[z[0]][z[1]] == 'X':
                if randint(0, 1):
                    set = None
                    if rch == 'u':
                        set = (z[0]+1, z[1])
                    elif rch == 'd':
                        set = (z[0]-1, z[1])
                    elif rch == 'r':
                        set = (z[0], z[1]-1)
                    elif rch == 'l':
                        set = (z[0], z[1]+1)
                    else:
                        pass
                    if maze[set[0]][set[1]] == '_':
                        # Checks so that no walls that block the entire way are formed
                        # Makes sure maze is solvable
                        sets, count = [
                            (set[0]+1, set[1]), (set[0]-1, set[1]), (set[0], set[1]+1), (set[0], set[1]-1)], 0
                        for blyat in sets:
                            while blyat[0] != 0 and blyat[1] != 0 and blyat[0] != order+1 and blyat[1] != order+1:
                                ch = [(blyat[0]+1, blyat[1]), (blyat[0]-1, blyat[1]),
                                      (blyat[0], blyat[1]+1), (blyat[0], blyat[1]-1)]
                                suka = []
                                for i in ch:
                                    if ch not in suka:
                                        if maze[i[0]][i[1]] == 'X':
                                            blyat = i
                                            break
                                        else:
                                            pass
                                        suka.append(ch)
                                    else:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    blyat = None
                                if blyat == None:
                                    break
                                else:
                                    pass
                            else:
                                count += 1
                        if count < 1:
                            maze[set[0]][set[1]] = 'X'
                            blocks.append(set)
                        else:
                            pass
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
        b += 1

    mazebuilder(maze, order)
    spit()
```

Sorry for leaving this out!

Comment: where does maze_builderV2 come from ?

Comment: @Setop It is my custom maze generating algorithm. It generates mazes that have multiple correct paths.

Comment: so we can't test and profile your code. How do you expect us to help you ?

Comment: @Setop Ok I am sorry, give me a minute, I will edit post to include that as well.

Comment: @Setop I have edited the post and have included my maze-builder algorithm! Feel free to ask me for anything else that I might have missed out that you may need to analyse my A-star algorithm!

Comment: You might get good answers on [the CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) too, your question would fit since your code works but you're looking to improve it

Comment: @Aaron Ok, thanks! If I don't get any answers here, I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Just at a quick glance, it looks like you don't have a closed set at all??  Your `unvisited` structure appears to contain every node in the map.  This algorithm is not A* at all.

Once you fix that, make sure to change `unvisited` from a list to a priority queue also.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant, can you explain a bit more in detail about what is wrong and what I am supposed to do? Thanks by the way!

Comment: @Prithvidiamond: What you're doing wrong is that this is a completely different algorithm.  I'm not sure what advice to give besides "look at a description of the algorithm and implement that"

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the advice!

Comment: " it looks like you don't have a closed set at all?? Your unvisited structure appears to contain every node in the map. " I did not understand what you meant by this line... Could you please elaborate on this...